# Java objects cannot be deserialized because of class structure change

Tags: java

I had serialized some objects of class into a file later the class structure had modified. So I cannot deserialize my object back. Please let me know how can I restore these objects?

Comment: If your class structure has been changed,then why do you want to get it back? I guess it would be of no use.

Answer (score 3):

To make it short: You should use your previous version of your java class and use it to read the serialized objects. Then you'll have to make a transition piece of software reading previous data and filling fields in the new object with this data before serializing this new version of your object.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Revert your class as it was before.
2. Create a new class which will have the new features.
3. Write an adapter class which places one class (the old) into another (the new).
4. Serialize the new version.